# Error in Array comparison in php

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, foreach, zend-framework2

Below are the sample arrays I'm Comparing.

**Table 1**

```
 $csvData=
 (
 [0] =&gt; Array
    (
        [Account Number] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [Posting Date] =&gt; 2014/07/08
        [Value Date] =&gt; 2014/07/08
        [Description] =&gt; Cash Withdrawal by Cheque-173320--TT1421957901
        [Debit Amount] =&gt; 2000
        [Credit Amount] =&gt; 
        [Running Balance] =&gt; 388392.62
    )

[1] =&gt; Array
    (
        [Account Number] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [Posting Date] =&gt; 2014/07/08
        [Value Date] =&gt; 2014/07/08
        [Description] =&gt; Cheque Paid-173261--TT1421951241
        [Debit Amount] =&gt; 855
        [Credit Amount] =&gt; 
        [Running Balance] =&gt; 390392.62
    )

[2] =&gt; Array
    (
        [Account Number] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [Posting Date] =&gt; 2014/07/08
        [Value Date] =&gt; 2014/07/08
        [Description] =&gt; Cheque Paid-173298--TT1421951226
        [Debit Amount] =&gt; 1895
        [Credit Amount] =&gt; 
        [Running Balance] =&gt; 391247.62
    )

[3] =&gt; Array
    (
        [Account Number] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [Posting Date] =&gt; 2014/06/08
        [Value Date] =&gt; 2014/06/08
        [Description] =&gt; Cash Withdrawal by Cheque-173319--TT1421858465
        [Debit Amount] =&gt; 2750
        [Credit Amount] =&gt; 
        [Running Balance] =&gt; 393142.62
    )

)
```

**Table 2**

```
 $dbData=
        (
    [12] =&gt; Array
    (
        [JournalReferenceId] =&gt; 12
        [DebitAmount] =&gt; 3500.00
        [CreditAmount] =&gt; 0.00
        [Description] =&gt; 
        [JournalReferenceCreatedDate] =&gt; 2015-04-27 15:51:53
        [JournalId] =&gt; 4
        [ChequeNumber] =&gt; 
        [ChequeDate] =&gt; 
        [AccountNumber] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [bankId] =&gt; 15
        [BankReconcileId] =&gt; 
        [IsPresent] =&gt; 
        [CreatedDate] =&gt; 
        [CreatedBy] =&gt; 
        [JournalApprovedBy] =&gt; 
    )

[20] =&gt; Array
    (
        [JournalReferenceId] =&gt; 20
        [DebitAmount] =&gt; 350.00
        [CreditAmount] =&gt; 0.00
        [Description] =&gt; 
        [JournalReferenceCreatedDate] =&gt; 2015-04-27 15:53:42
        [JournalId] =&gt; 6
        [ChequeNumber] =&gt; 
        [ChequeDate] =&gt; 
        [AccountNumber] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [bankId] =&gt; 15
        [BankReconcileId] =&gt; 
        [IsPresent] =&gt; 
        [CreatedDate] =&gt; 
        [CreatedBy] =&gt; 
        [JournalApprovedBy] =&gt; 
    )

[56] =&gt; Array
    (
        [JournalReferenceId] =&gt; 56
        [DebitAmount] =&gt; 26.40
        [CreditAmount] =&gt; 0.00
        [Description] =&gt; Initial Amount
        [JournalReferenceCreatedDate] =&gt; 2015-04-27 16:40:35
        [JournalId] =&gt; 18
        [ChequeNumber] =&gt; 
        [ChequeDate] =&gt; 
        [AccountNumber] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [bankId] =&gt; 15
        [BankReconcileId] =&gt; 
        [IsPresent] =&gt; 
        [CreatedDate] =&gt; 
        [CreatedBy] =&gt; 
        [JournalApprovedBy] =&gt; 
    )

[68] =&gt; Array
    (
        [JournalReferenceId] =&gt; 68
        [DebitAmount] =&gt; 20.66
        [CreditAmount] =&gt; 0.00
        [Description] =&gt; Initial Amount
        [JournalReferenceCreatedDate] =&gt; 2015-04-27 16:49:33
        [JournalId] =&gt; 21
        [ChequeNumber] =&gt; 
        [ChequeDate] =&gt; 
        [AccountNumber] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [bankId] =&gt; 15
        [BankReconcileId] =&gt; 
        [IsPresent] =&gt; 
        [CreatedDate] =&gt; 
        [CreatedBy] =&gt; 
        [JournalApprovedBy] =&gt; 
    )

[88] =&gt; Array
    (
        [JournalReferenceId] =&gt; 88
        [DebitAmount] =&gt; 3332112.00
        [CreditAmount] =&gt; 0.00
        [Description] =&gt; 
        [JournalReferenceCreatedDate] =&gt; 2015-05-05 18:29:47
        [JournalId] =&gt; 28
        [ChequeNumber] =&gt; 
        [ChequeDate] =&gt; 
        [AccountNumber] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [bankId] =&gt; 15
        [BankReconcileId] =&gt; 
        [IsPresent] =&gt; 
        [CreatedDate] =&gt; 
        [CreatedBy] =&gt; 
        [JournalApprovedBy] =&gt; 1
    )

[136] =&gt; Array
    (
        [JournalReferenceId] =&gt; 136
        [DebitAmount] =&gt; 359.14
        [CreditAmount] =&gt; 0.00
        [Description] =&gt; Initial Amount
        [JournalReferenceCreatedDate] =&gt; 2015-05-13 15:50:51
        [JournalId] =&gt; 42
        [ChequeNumber] =&gt; 
        [ChequeDate] =&gt; 
        [AccountNumber] =&gt; 1.01100156278101E+15
        [bankId] =&gt; 15
        [BankReconcileId] =&gt; 
        [IsPresent] =&gt; 
        [CreatedDate] =&gt; 
        [CreatedBy] =&gt; 
        [JournalApprovedBy] =&gt; 
    )
```

**Code**

```
   foreach ($dbData as $dbRow) {


        $csv_ied_account_number = ($this->_convertDbValueToCsvLikeValue($this->_csvColumnAccountNumber, $dbRow));

        $datetime = ($this->_convertDbValueToCsvLikeValue($this->_csvColumnJournalDate, $dbRow));
        $dt = new DateTime($datetime);

        $csv_ied_journal_date = $dt->format('m/d/Y');

        $csv_ied_debit_amount = ($this->_convertDbValueToCsvLikeValue($this->_csvColumnDebitAmount, $dbRow));

        $csv_ied_credit_amount = ($this->_convertDbValueToCsvLikeValue($this->_csvColumnCreditAmount, $dbRow)); 

  /*Compare with csv and db data*/ 

       $CsvValues = array();     
        foreach ($csvData as $key => $csvRow) {


       if ((($csvRow[$this->_csvColumnAccountNumber]) === $csv_ied_account_number) &&
                    (($csvRow[$this->_csvColumnJournalDate]) === $csv_ied_journal_date) ) {

                 $CsvValues[$key]= 1;  
            }
        }


        if (count($CsvValues) > 0) {
            asort($CsvValues);
            $key = key($CsvValues); 
            $dbRow['IsPresent'] = 1;
            unset($csvData[$key]);
        }
```

**note**
The table headers have been declared globally.So no problem with that.

The code  I've used is only comparing the first row,but Its supposed to be comparing the entire row with each of the database rows and pass the **  $dbRow['IsPresent'] = 1** corresponding to that row.Please help me on this.I've been spending a hell lot of time with this.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: The output should be like   **$dbRow['IsPresent'] = 1;** for each of the dbrow , where all the columns present in  a dbrow matches with that of the csvdata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,simply by using

```
(($csvRow[$this->_csvColumnJournalDate]) == $csv_ied_journal_date) )
```

instead of

```
 (($csvRow[$this->_csvColumnJournalDate]) === $csv_ied_journal_date) )
```

now works like a charm!

**==** for same value

**===** same data type type and value